# Debian-64bit-6.0.3 IspCP i can't reach any php files but other are okay any solutions?

Tags: php, mysql, debian

my server is Debian-64bit-6.0.3 IspCP   i can't reach any php file of my website on browser but others are okay(html,js etc.). I propably made a mistake(adding,deleting) while i was editing php.ini files and i can't find where  the mistake is now

```
any solution suggestions?
```

Comment: Impossible to say anything until you provide more info: are the files physically on server? Can they be launched through bash: $php filename.php?

Comment: i dont know i  am sorry i am not so familiar with linux and servers,all i can say files are on server i had reached them on browser with no problem till i went into putty to make some changes on the php.ini to increase max upload filesize

Comment: Try to revert the changes